# How to calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{x}{tg^2x}$ without De L'Hopital?

Tags: calculus, limits

I would like to calculate the following limit: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{x}{tg^2x}$ without using De L'Hopital rule. I know that as $x\rightarrow 0^+$, it gives an indeterminate form of the type $\frac{0}{0}$. Therefore using De L'Hopital seems a reasonable choice, but I was wondering if we could calculate the limit using some kind of algebraic manipulation.

Comment: I do not know of any simple algebraic manipulation but without using De L'Hôpital, remember that $\tan x \underset{x\to 0^+}{\sim}x$ is just enough to conclude here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y = \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x}{\tan^2x} = \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^2}{x\tan^2x} = \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x} = \infty$

As, $\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{x} = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x} = +\infty$, the limit doesn't exist at 0

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than the limit itself, use Taylor expansions
$$\tan(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
$$\frac x {\tan^2(x)}=\frac x {\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^5\right)\right)^2}=\frac x {x^2+\frac{2 x^4}{3}+O\left(x^6\right)}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2 x}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.